# Eclipse Egit stucks at Getting Remote Branches Information

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit, freeze

I have installed Egit Plugin from the below update link
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

and the following got installed

```
Eclipse Git Team Provider   3.2.0.201312181205-r
Eclipse Git Team Provider - Source Code 3.2.0.201312181205-r
Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team Provider    3.2.0.201312181205-r
```

Now i am trying to clone a URI using Import option
The link i am trying for instance is github.com/googleglass

and egit is getting stuck as per the png on below link

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/12/egitissue.png

Tried uninstalling and installing multiple version
tried changing the buffer size in preferences.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or a firewall? This can block the necessary calls and will keep your egit just wait.

Comment: Note that the Egit plugin is still under development (a few years ago I had to delete and recreate a few of my Github repos because something very strange happened). I'd ask the guys for support: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/support/

Answer (score 0):

The URL in the question does not look like a Git repository URL:

http://github.com/googleglass

You need to go to a specific repository and select the clone URL there, e.g. try this:

https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-level-sample.git